# IO Exception looking for File Path using DOM in android

Tags: android, dom, filepath, ioexception

There are a few posts re: this topic but can't figure out why this won't work. 
Keep getting an `IOException`. Guessing it can't find the file. Cheers.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory  = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("//res/xml/xml_data.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change yours with this

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory  = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("res/xml/xml_data.xml");
```

Comment: thanks, i knew about it(XmlResourceParser) because i once work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is incorrect. Resources take the form:

```
"android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]"
```

or

```
"android.resource://[package]/[res id]
```

ie

```
"android.resource://com.org.example/xml/xml_data" // No extension

"android.resource://com.org.example/" + R.xml.xml_data
```

Comment: Thanks but I keep getting the error...W/System.err(332): java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: android.resource...so still issues with the file path trying to use DOM to read in the xml file. Any advice would be great. Cheers.